# To Load Truck with only one Type (one color)

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to create a function where one truck only take an order with one type. In the example model Distribution Center an order includes several types. In my simulation I would like to have only one type (one color) in the loading docks as well as in the loadingtrucks. Is this possible and how could I do this?

[Example: Distribution Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3lX5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible. Create a "myColor" parameter in your Order agent (type Color). Then, when it comes to RackPick, you can use a condition similar to 'agent.myColor.equals(Color.red)' to only pick orders with a red color value...

HOWEVER: it seems like you need to learn a lot of things first before you can do that easily. I strongly suggest you study all tutorials in the help first to understand the core concepts better (agent types, parameters, coding...).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No worries. If the answer was helpful, please mark that (up-arrow next to the answer). Will help others find things faster in the future :)